How to fetch metaplex metadata for Token2022?
Currently I have a method I use to get the Metaplex Metadata for a token, but it only works with the regular token program and for tokens from the Token2022 program I can't seem to find a method that works to get the metadata. Does anyone know how it can be done. Also I will not be using any API's, I want to determine it purely from on-chain data.
I have internal methods name the .map and .decode, these are purely to assign on-chain byte data to their relevant structures, but the main issue is that the get_account_info call returns None.
    async def get_token_metadata(self, token_address: str) -> Union[METAPLEX_METADATA, None]:
        """
        Returns the Metaplex Metadata of a token. Does not support SPL Token 2022 program.

        @param token_address: The address of the token.

        @return The metadata of the token.
        """
        try:
            pda = str((Pubkey.find_program_address(
                seeds = [
                    b'metadata',
                    bytes(_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM),
                    bytes(Pubkey.from_string(token_address)),
                ],
                program_id = _TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM
            ))[0])

            account_info = (await self._w3.get_account_info(
                    pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(pda)
                ))
            account_json = json.loads(account_info.to_json())
            if account_json["result"]["value"] is None:
                return None
            account_data =  METAPLEX_METADATA.decode(data = base64.b64decode(account_json["result"]["value"]["data"][0]))
            metadata = await METAPLEX_METADATA.map(account = str(pda), decoded_data = account_data)

            return metadata
        except Exception:
            raise



Looks like the Token Metadata program is incompatible with Token 2022: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/d88d7d0c2db3aebe9f2fdef7185c7c4248a1ab05/programs/token-metadata/program/src/processor/mod.rs#L350
Can possibly just parse the native Token 2022 metadata to get the info you're looking for. Not sure what assets you're working with.

Yeah seems like Token2022 tokens write their token metadata directly into the mint account itself. Thanks for the response
